# Solitaire game design

Tags: project

I want to build a solitaire game in C++ for my project.

Here's what I have come up with: Card class Properties/members: Suit,Rank,Color(All of these can be enums) Actions/Functions: Flip card, compare card, print card Rules Class: Would contain the rules of the game and also validate each user action/command to check if it is allowed. Commands Class: I am thinking this need not necessarily be a class. Could be an enum as well. A base class CardPile. Have more classes derived from CardPile such as DealPile, Temporary Pile, DestinationPile, TablePile. What I am not clear about is the relationships between classes.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest politely that you will have a clearer understanding of a design that you work out yourself rather than one which is spoon-fed to you.

Comment: I wouldn't go overboard with your "modeling."  There are numerous open source references.  The glue is the GUI modifying the more "abstract" cards which are placed in piles or stacks etc...  The best way to determine how they all come together is just to code the darn thing!

Comment: I'll give you the benefit of the doubt; maybe you have done more work on this and just wanted to bang out a quick post here. If you've done more work than what you stated, please post it. Otherwise this just reads as "This is hard and I don't feel like trying right now"...and that's how most people will take it.

Comment: Rather than just toss out class for every solitaire-connected word you can think of, try thinking about it like a real game.  It makes sense for each card to be an object -- it's rank, suit, and color etc. would be data members on the class (just like they are pieces of information on a real card).  Take your time and you'll be able to come up with a decent design... unless this is due in 10 minutes, in which case you better call your prof and come up with some lame excuse!

Comment: "sorry I asked guys..I had asked only to get started in the right direction" When you have homework questions the best thing to do is try doing some of it yourself and then ask specific questions about something you are unsure of. Just don't throw the whole bag out there and hope someone will design a whole solitaire game for you.

Comment: Well when I typed, it came out thhat way.
Here's what I had in mind:
Card class
Properties/members: Suit,Rank,Color(All of these can be enums)
Actions/Functions: Flip card, compare card, print card
Rules Class:
Would contain the rules of the game and also validate each user action/command to check if it is allowed.
Commands Class: I am thinking this need not necessarily be a class. Could be an enum as well.
A base class CardPile. Have more classes derived from CardPile such as DealPile, Temporary Pile, DestinationPile, TablePile.
What I am not clear about is the relationships between classes.

Comment: IF you're still around, AgentHunt, have a look at what I wrote below.  I recognize the way you're developing, because it's how I started too.  It's called *object-oriented* programming, which leads new programmers to think they're supposed to start by creating a bunch of *objects* and then string them together.  My experience over the years has been that this just creates clutter.  An object isn't useful to your program unless and until it *does* something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a representation of a card which will hold the card's value and suit.

You will also need a data structure to represent a "stack" of cards.

From there, building the GUI shouldn't be that challenging. This is a very easy project, and you seem to have the right idea.

Comment: Yes, I hadnt thought about having a data stucture to represent the stack of cards. I was thinking in terms of different kinds of decks/piles. But may be I could have a separte datastructure and use it in the decks/piles. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider, instead of doing a bunch of up-front design, focusing on creating things that work.  What will your program need to do?

It'll need to shuffle, so design a way to represent 52 cards and shuffle them.  It's pretty easy to implement, but it's a good starting point.

Then you'll need to lay out the cards.  So come up with a way to lay out the cards and put the rest in the draw pile.

And so forth.  Instead of analyzing objects, focus on *behaviors*.  Create objects only as needed in order to support the behaviors of your program.  That will help you avoid getting lost in the analysis and excess code and ensure that you have a program that actually does some useful things.

(What if you need to turn in your design before doing anything?  Not a problem; do your *thinking* the way I've described above.  The implementation will be left for later, but even just thinking out how routines like the above will work will be more valuable than designing a bunch of objects without knowing what you'll do with them.)